# In MySQL is there a variable for the current database?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have a script that I run on multiple databases and to run on multiple databases I just change the MySql "USE" statement.

I'm wanting to have a select statement that outputs the current database the script is executing against as a field.

For example:

```
USE my_db;

SELECT 
  CURRENT_DB, -- this is where to insert the current executing db, i.e. "my_db"
  id, name, blah, blah
FROM my_table
```

Comment: I did search for longer than I expected. Google & Bing were being picky and not finding it. Probably because I was searching for a variable and not a db function.

Comment: Your first place to look should be the manual, not google or bing.

Comment: The manual was in the search results, but was mainly pointing to db_name in the manual. Again, my issue was I was searching for a variable and not a function.

Comment: i want to know why more people cannot answer by saying something like, "why not look in the manual? i found the answer, here it is ...[then post the answer]", thereby helping and not wasting a reply.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the `database()` function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database

Comment: What's interesting is that it does not work in SQLyog. I guess it just adds the database name to every table name in the query before executing it.

Comment: @Shedal - I would say that's a bug with SQLyog then, since this is a documented function straight out of MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 23):

use **DATABASE()**

Returns the default (current) database name as a string in the utf8 character set. If there is no default database, DATABASE() returns NULL. Within a stored routine, the default database is the database that the routine is associated with, which is not necessarily the same as the database that is the default in the calling context.

**for Example**

```
  mysql> SELECT DATABASE();
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this snippet:

```
select database();
```